# Proof that $\sqrt{20}$ is irrational number validation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

$$\sqrt{20}=\frac{m}{n}$$
$$20n^2=m^2$$
$$m = 20q \implies 20n^2=400q^2$$
$$n^2 = 20q^2 \implies \frac{n^2}{m^2} = \frac{20q^2}{20q} \implies \text{Contradiction}$$

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: No.  It is not true that $20\,|\,m^2\implies 20\,|\,m$.  For instance, $20\,|\,10^2$.  This is why one tends to use these arguments for primes (as $p\,|\,m^2$ does imply $p\,|\,m$ if $p$ is prime).  As a hint:  it's easy to reduce your case to a prime case.

Comment: @lulu So if I understand correctly I would do the same but for $5$ instead of $20$ ?

Comment: $\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt{5}$, so prove that $\sqrt 5$ is irrational :)

Comment: @BiliDebili  That's right.  First remark that $\sqrt {20}\in \mathbb Q$ is the same as $\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q$.  Then repeat your argument using $5$ instead of $20$.  Alternatively, just show that $5$ must divide both $m$ and $n$ in your current argument.  That's enough since it proves that $\frac mn$ can never be written in least terms.

Comment: As an instructor I would seriously critique this proof even if it were correct, since it has no words. You need lots of "suppose" and "therefore" and "it follows that" to make it readable. As for logical correctness I think you need something like "we can assume $m/n$ is written in lowest terms" with an argument if your instructor wants one.

Comment: @EthanBolker . Yes. One's math should be presented to others in complete grammatically correct sentences with proper punctuation, and should never omit words such as "suppose","if" , "iff", "then", "implies", "therefore", or "because".